# javaws Heap Space error (OutOfMemoryError)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am using a web application which downloads and runs java program on the browser through JNLP & javaws. Very randomly in my machine, I'm getting this "OutOfMemoryError". This doesn't happen to anyone who is consuming that web application.

Is it fine if I build a simple program to do Garbage collection and execute it before launching the web application, so that the space is cleared in memory ?

I have another question with JVM. Now lets say that I have 5 java processes running in my machine which are using java.exe from same jre folder. Will each java process have separate JVM ? or all processes will be running on same JVM ?

If we do GC from one java process, will it clears memory only for that process or will it clears on all other processes as well ?

Comment: Rule of thumb, each java process is independent of each other if launched independently, hence, JVM is independent, and so is GC process.

Comment: ok Thanks for clarifying that. I have only JRE on the remote machine where I open the web application in browser. How can I monitor the Heap Space of javaws to understand how much memory is currently allocated and possibly increase it though run arguments on control panel . In my local I had jdk, hence I was using jstat, but how do I do it on other windows servers where only JRE is available.

Comment: There are a couple of ways you can do that, but I assume your server does not have UI support and you will be accessing it through ssh terminal, then you can take heap dump on the server(for this you need JDK on the server :( ), transfer it to local machine and do a heap dump analysis.

Comment: Are you aware that you are riding a dead horse?

Comment: @Holger Why so ? :)

Comment: Webstart has been removed from Java. That makes it unlikely that maintaining Webstart applications becomes better.